# Performance of Enumerable that tries to replicate LINQ OrderBy

Tags: c#, performance, linq, mono, ienumerable

I was trying to implement an Enumerable that replicates what LINQ `OrderBy` does. To do so, I used two approaches:

1. I used Mono's Linq/Enumerable.cs as base and replicated the `OrderBy` code in my Enumerable.
2. I used a decompiler to get an impression of .NET's version and replicated that code.

When benchmarking the LINQ version versus both options (I used `.Take(10)` to print less output), the linq version is significantly faster (1900ms vs 3700ms). The source data was `List<MyObject>`, sorted by char member. Optimized `build flag was on`.

Could someone please explain me where this difference could come from?

Edit:
I will outline the code for 2. below:

Here, `Buffer<TElement>` is a copy of `System.Linq.Buffer<TElement>` (copied from `ILSpy` as it is internal) and `Sort` is (mostly) copied in the same way from `System.Linq.EnumerableSorter<TElement>`.

```
public class Query2F
{
    private Func<Lineitem, char> keySelector;
    private char[] keys;
    private IComparer<char> comparer;
    private bool descending;

    public Query2F(Func<Lineitem, char> keySelector, bool descending)
    {
        this.keySelector = keySelector;
        this.descending = descending;
        this.comparer = Comparer<char>.Default;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Lineitem> Execute(List<Lineitem> lineitem)
    {
        Buffer<Lineitem> buffer = new Buffer<Lineitem>(lineitem);
        if (buffer.count > 0)
        {
            Query2F q2f = new Query2F((s => s.returnflag), false);
            int[] array = q2f.Sort(buffer.items, buffer.count);
            q2f = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.count; i++)
            {
                yield return buffer.items[array[i]];
            }
        }
        yield break;
    }

    private void ComputeKeys(Lineitem[] elements, int count)
    {
        this.keys = new char[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            //this.keys[i] = this.keySelector(elements[i]);
            this.keys[i] = elements[i].returnflag;
        }
    }

    private int CompareKeys(int index1, int index2)
    {
        int num = this.comparer.Compare(this.keys[index1], this.keys[index2]);
        if (num == 0)
        {
            return index1 - index2;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!this.descending)
            {
                return num;
            }
            return -num;
        }
    }

    internal int[] Sort(Lineitem[] elements, int count)
    {
        this.ComputeKeys(elements, count);
        int[] array = new int[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            array[i] = i;
        }
        this.QuickSort(array, 0, count - 1);
        return array;
    }

    private void QuickSort(int[] map, int left, int right)
    {
        do
        {
            int num = left;
            int num2 = right;
            int index = map[num + (num2 - num >> 1)];
            do
            {
                if (num < map.Length)
                {
                    if (this.CompareKeys(index, map[num]) > 0)
                    {
                        num++;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                while (num2 >= 0 && this.CompareKeys(index, map[num2]) < 0)
                {
                    num2--;
                }
                if (num > num2)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (num < num2)
                {
                    int num3 = map[num];
                    map[num] = map[num2];
                    map[num2] = num3;
                }
                num++;
                num2--;
            }
            while (num <= num2);
            if (num2 - left <= right - num)
            {
                if (left < num2)
                {
                    this.QuickSort(map, left, num2);
                }
                left = num;
            }
            else
            {
                if (num < right)
                {
                    this.QuickSort(map, num, right);
                }
                right = num2;
            }
        }
        while (left < right);
    }
}

internal struct Buffer<TElement>
{
    internal TElement[] items;
    internal int count;
    internal Buffer(IEnumerable<TElement> source)
    {
        TElement[] array = null;
        int num = 0;
        ICollection<TElement> collection = source as ICollection<TElement>;
        if (collection != null)
        {
            num = collection.Count;
            if (num > 0)
            {
                array = new TElement[num];
                collection.CopyTo(array, 0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (TElement current in source)
            {
                if (array == null)
                {
                    array = new TElement[4];
                }
                else
                {
                    if (array.Length == num)
                    {
                        TElement[] array2 = new TElement[checked(num * 2)];
                        Array.Copy(array, 0, array2, 0, num);
                        array = array2;
                    }
                }
                array[num] = current;
                num++;
            }
        }
        this.items = array;
        this.count = num;
    }
    internal TElement[] ToArray()
    {
        if (this.count == 0)
        {
            return new TElement[0];
        }
        if (this.items.Length == this.count)
        {
            return this.items;
        }
        TElement[] array = new TElement[this.count];
        Array.Copy(this.items, 0, array, 0, this.count);
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like it depends on **the actual implementation** you've done?

Comment: The actual implementation is quite a bit of code as it uses classes and methods that are internal to System.LINQ and I also had to replicate them. I will try to outline it above.

Comment: When you use third-party `LINQ` stuff, there is a chance that the provider doesn't implement it in the best way, so your problem can be understandable, You can only know the reason if you know the **internal implementation** of the third-part `LINQ` stuff.

Comment: Now you lost me. With _third-party_ you mean the _decompiled_ _Microsoft_ _LINQ_ code? My assumption was that using this code, my `Enumerable` and the `.Net` implementation should be mostly equivalent. This is the reason why I do not understand the performance difference. Unless there are differences between the decompiled code and the original code or `.NET` uses better optimizations for System libraries.

Comment: So what is `Buffer`? What is `Query2F`? Even if they are not third-party stuff, they're the problem here, even I don't really understand what the code you post does. When you want to **compare** 2 implementations of code, you should post both the two. while you post only 1?

Comment: Added all the code (In case I am not allowed to post decompiled code here, please remove). But the point should have been that the code should not matter because it _should_ be the _same_ as used by the default `IEnumerable` query provider.

Comment: wow, fairly much code, I can see there are fairly many `loops` in the middle, they are not nested loops but may require a considerable time when the input is large. I'm not sure about the actual reason, but I think the `LINQ OrderBy` doesn't use such much code, the `input` is always an `IEnumerable` and use a `while` loop to `yield` everything, I think the `ComputeKeys` is redundant, you can access the `OrderBy element` easily from the element based on `pointer`, so why do we need it? I'm not sure how `OrderBy` is implemented internally in `LINQ`, but it should be the best...

Comment: I would like to say that the most experienced developers made `LINQ` so it will have some `unbeatable` implementation. Although in fact I've done some code which outperforms `LINQ` just by normal `for-loop` on `List`. BTW the `CompareKeys` may consume you much `calling time`, I don't think we need such a method, why not somehow use the `Comparer` passed in directly?

Comment: The last, `QuickSort` is not always the best, I guess the internal implementation of `LINQ` has been being updated with the latest best sorting algorithm based on the best `structure`.

Comment: Just to clarify: This _IS_ the internal `LINQ` implementation! Or at least what a `.NET` decompiler outputs. So my question is not about how to make it faster, but why two equivalent (my assumption based on the above) pieces of code perform so differently.

Comment: Was your 'equivalent' code compiled in 'Release' mode (as opposed to 'Debug' mode)?  That alone could have a substantial impact.

Comment: It was (`Release`, `x64`, `Optimized`). <br> In the meantime, I also 1:1 copied the decompiled code into my source file (the `OrderBy` extension method and all classes it uses) and got the same results. The only difference between both remains two attributes that I could not use (`[__DynamicallyInvokable]` and `[TargetedPatchingOptOut("..")]`). This suggests to me that it has to be either them, some decompilation problem or that `.NET` treats libraries differently to user code.

Comment: @Mike You were right. I ran it from `Visual Studio` with `Release` selected. However, turns out that when I ran the executable outside `Visual Studio`, both options performed similarly. Sorry for wasting everyone's time. Is there a way to run the release build from `VS2012`?

Comment: Run without the debugger attached: DEBUG menu -> Start Without Debugging (`Ctrl+F5`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.Thanks to Mike for pointing me to the solution.

The reason for the discrepancies in the execution time were merely that I executed the wrong build (which was not a Release build).